# How to post parameter value to some actionlink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In my view i have 10 link every link associated with some unique value. Now i want that associated value at my controller action and from that action i want to redirect the flow to some other action based on that value. 

But the condition is i dont want to display it on url.

How can i acheive this?

- I tried `ajax.post/@Ajax.ActionLink` but doing this will not facilitate redirect to another action.
- Is there anything with route i need to do?

**View**

```
    <ul>@foreach (var item in Model)
    {<li>
  @Ajax.ActionLink(item.pk_name, "Index","Candidate", new { para1= item.para1 }
             , new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })</li>
    }</ul>
```

**Action**

```
[HttPost]
public ActionResult(int para1)
{
return RedirectToAction(para1,"anotherController");
}
```

I am getting value at para1 with ajax post(that is what i primarily needed) but here also want to redirect my application flow base on para1 value which is action name.

**Confision** : here i am not sure is this is the right way to do this thing. So i am asking you guys should i go for route map of working with ajax post will solve my objective.

Comment: What exactly don't you want as part of the link url?

Comment: if you post more of your solution its easier to se what you are doing, mainly the html, and how does your first action look like (the in parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to redirect the user based on what he clicks on without showing him the link, I believe the best way to achieve this is by client-side coding.

In my opinion there is no need to take any request through the server in order to change the page for such a low-complexity redirect.

**View**

```
// HTML
// Might be broken, been awhile since I worked with MVC
// Can't really remember if that's how you put variables in HTML
<ul id="button-list">
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <li class="buttonish" data-para1="@item.para1">@item.pk_name</li>
    }
</ul>

// JS
// I wouldn't do any server related work
$('#button-list li.buttonish').click(function(){
    // Your controller and action just seem to redirect to another controller and send in the parameter
    window.location.href = "/controller/method/" + $(this).data('para1');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make one jQuery function that is call when clicked and pass unique parameter.In that function you can use AJAX and post it on appropriate controller method.

Example:

```
<input type="button" id="@item.pk_name" onclick="getbuttonvalue(@item.para1);"  />
```

In script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
function getbuttonvalue(para1) {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',

                url: "/controller/method/" + para1,

                success: function (data) {
                }

            });
```

`}`

```
 });
```

`</script>`